# How to launch Android PayPal Mobile app using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, paypal

If a user owes me money, I want to start Paypal mobile app from my app using Intent with amount and payee information preset, all the user has to do is to verify the information and either confirm to pay or cancel to decline.  Could someone show me how to initialize the intent, please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how complicated you want to make it, but with PayPal it can be as simple as popping over to a full browser window with a URL structured like the following:

https://www.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_xclick&item_name=description%20of%20payment&amount=77%2e88&currency_code=USD&business=payee@example.com

Comment: I've tried the link and it looks very good so far.  You've made my day!   How to check the result (whether the user actually paid  or not)?    I want it as simple as possible, an easy way for user to pay.

Comment: Well reliable payment notifications are more complex. If you need it to be reliable and instant, you'll need to integrate something like the Orders V2 API from a server and redirect to the approval_url after creation.  The return_url given in creation can be a deeplink, but the ensuing capture that's triggered after return should be a fetch to a server that then does the capture (for it to be reliable).  This is getting much more sophisticated than the simple link

Comment: Your web link solution is pretty good as long as no result is needed.   Unfortunately for my case, I do need to find out whether the user has indeed paid or not.    I know Android Intent can be used to launch another app and get a result from the called app.    I just don't know how to setup the intent, hence my original question.

Comment: You'll still be launching a browser with a link. What you need is a server that implements the /v2/checkout/orders API. Alternatively you could integrate the Braintree SDK instead of /v2/checkout/orders, but you still need a webservice: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/checkout/how-to/braintree-integration/#integration-steps